# Unable to tap or select absolute position elements in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I am using the absolute position component as autocomplete for `<TextInput />` in the registration form, where I found an issue specific in Android & in iOS it's working fine.

I am unable to tap or select the autocomplete suggestions when trying to select the suggestions the fields behind the autocomplete are gaining the focus & suggestions being dismissed.

Added Z-index also even though the suggestion behaves just like a ghost.

Snack URL: https://snack.expo.io/@saivamshi/positioned-absolute-dropdown-issue

Comment: Can you share the code to deep dive into the behavior...

Comment: https://gitmemory.com/issue/facebook/react-native/25089/528192881

Comment: Have a try to use the toggleInspector to check the views and styles

Comment: Did you put `elevation`? because zIndex is ios only, and for android we use `elevation`

Comment: These are my style for the view:
`
{
          position: "absolute",
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          zIndex: 1,
          elevation: 2,
       }`

Elevation also not solved me the issue

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@saivamshi/positioned-absolute-dropdown-issue